# ReSharper 5.0 choking on strong-typed view model that's located in same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, resharper, resharper-5.0

I'm using VS2010, ASP.NET MVC 2, and ReSharper 5.0.  When I create a new view that's typed off of a model from the same project as my view, ReSharper doesn't see the reference to the model.

This is the definition of my view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Web.Domain.UserViewModel>" %>
```

Domain.UserViewModel is red, and the ReShaper tooltip to add a reference pops up.  This is really annoying because I cannot use intellisense for Model and ReSharper shows numerous errors in the view.

This is strictly a ReSharper code-inspection issue.  The view actually functions properly if I run the code.

If I change Web.Domain.UserViewModel to an object from another project then the red dissapears and everything is fine.  Does anyone know how I can make it recognize the models from the Web project correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try latest bug fix update, ReSharper 5.1?

Comment: No, I didn't realize it was out.  I should've checked.  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly issues? Did you create request in http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP?